# Having problems with borders on hovering in my vertical menu

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I have created a vertical menu and would like it to have a right red border on hover and selected item.

However, I can't seem to get it correct on hovering as my li border bottom seems to mess up the hover state. The bottom border slightly overlaps the right border.

Here is the code in a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/4KBE4/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="messaging">

    <div class="sideMenu"> 
        <ul class="messagesMenu">
            <li class="selected"><a href="#">Inbox<span>14</span></a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Outbox</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Address Book</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Trash</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </div> 

    <div class="messagesWrapper">
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.messaging {
    width: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.sideMenu {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;    
}
.messagesWrapper {
    background: honeydew;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    float: right;    
    min-height: 500px;
}
.messagesMenu {
    background: #FFF;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.messagesMenu li {
    padding: 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    height: 3em;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    border-right: 5px solid #d4d4d4;
}
.messagesMenu li:first-child { border-top: none; }
.messagesMenu li:last-child { border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4; }
.messagesMenu li a {
    line-height: 3em;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
    color: #c4c4c4;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.messagesMenu li a span {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #999;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    padding: 2px 6px;
}
.messagesMenu li:hover { border-right-color: #ed1c24; }
.messagesMenu li.selected { 
    border-right-color: #ed1c24;
    border-bottom: none;
}
.messagesMenu li.selected a { color: #2f3239; }
.clearfix { zoom: 1; }
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}​
```

Hope someone can help! Thanks :)

Comment: That is the expected behaviour. your border bottom has a size of 1px and is physically positioned under the side borders. What do you expect?

Answer (score 2):

Give the links `display: block`, remove their width: 100%, remove the `padding`, the `height` and the *horizontal* borders from the `li` and add them on the links.

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4KBE4/11/)

```
.messagesMenu li { border-right: 5px solid #d4d4d4; }
.messagesMenu li:first-child a { border-top: none; }
.messagesMenu li:last-child a { border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4; }
.messagesMenu li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 3em;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #c4c4c4;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 3em;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}
```

Comment: last link has white strip at the bottom. Text is not aligned at the center vertically

Comment: + That's great! actually the solution is not great (it's rather simple), but the quickness of the answer